# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Will not connect to wifi + wired connections are disabled

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

I've had no previous problems with connecting to the internet until today. When I log-in, there is no "wifi icon" in the upper right corner and when I try to connect to a wireless network using network manager, it won't let me, even though it says the wifi is ON.
Wired connection is OFF and when I click on it to turn it back on it just goes back to OFF immediately.

I'm not proficient with Ubuntu so didn't know what to do except:

`sudo service network-manager restart` - Changes nothing

`dhclient eth0` - Just hangs

EDIT: I've tried modifying some files and this is what got the internet working:

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I managed to connect to both wifi and ethernet only when the last two lines are present in that form. Also, my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file looks like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=3C:97:0E:02:F7:9B,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Although I can connect now to the internet, there is a "ifupdown(eth0)" connection which is bothering me (constantly trying to connect to it)

Additional info:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:31a1]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

I've solved the issue with connecting to the internet, it's just the "Ifupdown(eth0)" bugging me now, do I open a new question for this?

Answer (score 0):

When that happened to me last time it was because my computer has buttons to turn off the networks.

On a ThinkPad it can be a special button or shifter key somewhere on the computer.   On my Dell it's the <kbd>F2</kbd> key or <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key combo depending on which layer is activated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your laptop model?
Also, please edit your question details and paste the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Also, with a temporary internet connection, you could try

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
reboot
```

Post back if it worked out

Comment: Lenovo G580. This did not change anything.